# install4j how to handle java update

Tags: java, install4j

I have a Java app installed with Install4j.

The app started failing with the dreaded error "The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) might be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could block the execution"

After investigation it turned out that Java did an automatic upgrade from 8.111 to 8.131 and install4j was still going to the old version.  The fix was to edit \.install4j\inst_jre.cfg and change the contents from

```
c:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_111
```

to

```
c:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_131
```

However, that is not a very user friendly thing to have to do.  Is there any way to have the install use something more flexible?  Like going through C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath?  Or anything else.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Windows Java 8 installers (at least recent ones, I don't recall if this goes back to u0) copy the executables to programdata\oracle\java\javapath and add that directory to the system PATH envvar so you can just give `java` or `javaw` (or `javaws`) as the program to run and Windows will find it.

Comment: "and install4j was still going to the old version" -> Can you tell me how you found this out? Did you start with /create-i4j-log and saw in the log file that an old installation directory was used that does not exist anymore? install4j will detect if a previously used JRE is missing and do a new search, so this must be a specific problem.

Comment: I had a customer with a installation that was working, and one day started getting the JVM could not be started error.  I remoted to that computer and determined that Java had updated (automatically) on the day the error started.  I tried a lot of things to verify that Java was Ok, and jars with the app could be run, but not the install4j app.exe.  I finally edited the 'inst_jre.cfg' file, and presto everything worked.